# Calculate distance between points in polygon

Tags: python, list, numpy, math

I found a lot of posts on how to calculate distance between two points or from one point to polygon but I simply can't find how to calculate distance of each edge.
I have a polygon, where the coordinates are these:

```
 [[[623 284]] 

 [[526 256]]

 [[532 189]]

 [[504 166]]

 [[323 175]]

 [[276 219]]

 [[119 221]]

 [[  1 272]]

 [[  0 473]]

 [[615 479]]]
```

I simply want to calculate length of each edge. Maybe I should use `(math.dist(p, q))` with `for loop` or something?

Comment: Using `math.dist()` and a for loop would certainly work. To make your job easier there, you might consider `for p1, p2 in zip(points, points[1:]):` to work with pairs of subsequent points.

Comment: `[math.dist(p, q) for (p, q) in zip(points, points[1:]+[points[0]])]` or `[math.dist(points[i], points[(i+1)%len(points)]) for i in range(len(points))]` (the +[points[0]] and %len(points) are to include n-1 to 0 edge)

Comment: @AKX `for p1, p2 in zip(points, points[1:]+[points[0]])` if this is a closed polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If points coordinates are stored in two python lists `x` and `y`, then you can calculate each edge length with:

```
import numpy as np

x.append(x[0])
y.append(y[0])

d = [np.sqrt((x[i + 1] - x[i])**2 + (y[i + 1] - y[i])**2) for i in range(len(x) - 1)]
```

The `append` is required in order to close the polygon and calculate all edges length. With points you provided above, the edges distances are:

```
[100.96038827183659, 67.26812023536856, 36.235341863986875, 181.22361876973983, 64.38167441127949, 157.01273833673497, 128.5496013218244, 201.0024875467963, 615.0292675962665, 195.1640335717624]
```

Comment: It worked! I just want to add that I had nested array like I provided in the question, so firstly I had to separate x and y's like this:
x = [element[0][0] for element in array], y = [element[0][1] for element in array]

Comment: Is there some advantage about using `numpy.sqrt` here, rather than `math.sqrt` or `math.dist`?

Comment: No, `numpy.sqrt` and `math.sqrt` can be safely swapped. Don't know about `math.dist` because I am using python 3.7.0 and I can't upgrade on my machine

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a numpy array, the solution becomes very simple:

- calculate *vector* differences between adjacent points
- calculate the lengths of those vectors using a "norm", here the L2 norm, which is the *euclidean* norm

This uses whole-array operations.

```py
import numpy as np

points = np.array([
 [[623, 284]],
 [[526, 256]],
 [[532, 189]],
 [[504, 166]],
 [[323, 175]],
 [[276, 219]],
 [[119, 221]],
 [[  1, 272]],
 [[  0, 473]],
 [[615, 479]]])
# funny shape because OpenCV. it's a Nx1 vector of 2-channel elements
# fix that up, remove the silly dimension
points.shape = (-1, 2)

# look at the data, how it's moving the values around
following_points = np.roll(points, -1, axis=0)

# vector: difference between following point and this point
vectors = following_points - points

# length of a vector, using the L2/euclidean norm
lengths = np.linalg.norm(vectors, axis=1)

print("distance to following point:")
print(lengths)

# this is just for printing/displaying, not useful in code
print("point and distance to following point:")
print(np.hstack([points, lengths.reshape((-1, 1))]))
```

```
distance to following point:
[100.96039  67.26812  36.23534 181.22362  64.38167 157.01274 128.5496  201.00249 615.02927 195.16403]-89.72609 -88.20969]
point and distance to following point:
[[623.      284.      100.96039]
 [526.      256.       67.26812]
 [532.      189.       36.23534]
 [504.      166.      181.22362]
 [323.      175.       64.38167]
 [276.      219.      157.01274]
 [119.      221.      128.5496 ]
 [  1.      272.      201.00249]
 [  0.      473.      615.02927]
 [615.      479.      195.16403]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mathematical way to do this easily. With the 2D Pythagore's theorem :
For the following points:
A(x1,y1)
B(x2,x2)

Distance between the points :
D = sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 )

As a python script, you may create a function like this :

```
import math

A = [1,2]
B = [3, 3]

distance = math.sqrt( (B[0] - A[0])**2 + (B[1] - A[1])**2 )
```